# Is there a JS library that supports writing linq to sql queries with nodejs?

Tags: sql-server, linq, node.js

I see jslinq, and see tds js libraries for using node and SQL together... So has anyone ever used those technologies together?

I want to be able to write linq to sql queries in a nodejs app...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible, at least if you want to create ad-hoc queries in Javascript.  Linq (of any flavor) is a compiler technology.  A query using Linq syntax or Linq expressions is handled by the C# or VB compiler, not directly interpreted by the database.

A conventional way to do this would be through a web service in C#, using Linq to fetch and store data, and presenting a clean API to clients.  Then the client could consume the service through AJAX calls.

Answer (score 4):

I've started with JS variant of LINQ to Entities this week. Check [UniMapperJS](https://github.com/Hookyns/unimapperjs)

Example

```
var comments = await Comment.getAll()
.where(e => e.author.endsWith("something") || e.author.startsWith("somethingElse"))
.orderByDescending("created")
.limit(10)
.skip(0)
.exec();
```

But cuz of limitation of JS, it was hard to figure out, how to accept variables in **where** because that arrow functions are parsed as string. I've solved it by "virtual" variable ($) and list of args as last param.

```
var comments = await Comment.getAll()
.where(e => e.author.endsWith($) || e.author.startsWith($), filter.endsWith, filter.name)
.orderByDescending("created")
.limit(10)
.skip(0)
.select(e => e.author)
.exec();
```

Comment: I went even further and created TypeScript transformer [plugin](https://github.com/Hookyns/expression-transformer) which allows writing true Expression<> like in C#.
With this plugin, I write TypeORM LINQ-like wrapper (I don't create custom ORM (UniMapperJS anymore). See https://github.com/Hookyns/typeorm-linq.

Answer (score 3):

Today, JayData http://jaydata.org/ do it.

You can use the new ES6 Arrow Function syntax that looks very similar to C# (with a browser that supports it, like lastest Firefox, or a transpiler, like TypeScript or Traceur):

```
todoDB.Todos
    .filter(todo => todo.Completed == true)
    .map(todo => todo.Task )
    .forEach(taskName => $('#list')
    .append('Task: ' + taskName + ' completed'));
```

The query will be converted to a SQL Query (`select Task from Todos where Completed = true`) or a $filter URL parameter (`http://.../?$filter=Completed%20eq%201&$select=Task`), depending of the data source...

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) framework, it connects node.js with .Net. One way would be to use the built in T-SQL support in edge, and then use something like linq.js to manipulate the results.

```
var getTop10Products = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    select top 10 * from Products 
*/});

getTop10Product(null, function (error, products) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(products);
});
```

Otherwise, you could setup an EF datacontext in a .Net library and call out to that using Linq

```
var getTop10Product = edge.func(function () {/*
    async (input) => { 
      using (var db = new ProductContext())
      {
        //Linq to EF query
        var query = from b in db.Products
                    orderby b.Name
                    select b;
        return query.Take(10).ToList();
      }
    }
*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question today as I was wondering the same thing, and after a little more searching I came across [Squel](http://hiddentao.github.io/squel/).

Quoting directly from their website:

```
//this code
squel.select()
    .from("students")
    .field("name")
    .field("MIN(test_score)")
    .field("MAX(test_score)")
    .field("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')")
    .group("name")
);

/* will return this SQL query as a string:
    SELECT
        name,
        MIN(test_score),
        MAX(test_score),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
    FROM
        students
    GROUP BY
        name
*/
```

Hopefully this will help anyone who comes across this question while searching.

Good luck!

PS: <Insert standard disclaimer about not generating SQL queries in the browser...>

If you are creating client-side javascript that will send a SQL query to your database you open a whole can of worms - if the browser can dictate the SQL query, and a user can manipulate what comes from the browser, then you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**Bottom line: don't use this in the browser!**